# dpkg: error processing package dynare-matlab

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, matlab

My installation of Dynare isn't working. This is what I did:

- Manually added `deb http://www.dynare.org/ubuntu trusty main contrib` into sources.list file.
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install dynare-matlab

This is the output of the latter (removed some of the useless output):

```
Fetched 62.1 MB in 1min 42s (604 kB/s)                                         
Extract templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/matlab to provide /usr/bin/matlab (matlab) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/bin/matlab-mbuild because associated file /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/mbuild (of link group matlab) doesn't exist
Selecting previously unselected package imagemagick-common.
(Reading database ... 979203 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../imagemagick-common_8%3a6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3_all.deb ...
...
...
Building Matlab extensions (logfile at /tmp/dynare-matlab-mexbuild-1453562394.8blVBrS)
install: cannot stat ‘/usr/src/matlab/dynare-matlab/mex/matlab/*’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package dynare-matlab (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up aglfn (1.7-3) ...
...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dynare-matlab
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The installation prompted some questions, asking for installation folder and licence. That was fine. Any idea?

EDIT: just realised this problem arises when user name of Matlab version and user name of that chosen for dynare are different. I reconfigured again that bit (using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure matlab-support`). Then, tried again, but I got the following error:

```
Setting up dynare-matlab (4.4.1-1build1) ...
Building Matlab extensions (logfile at /tmp/dynare-matlab-mexbuild-1453566407.Ox9duw7)
In file included from ./tensor.hweb:53:0,
                 from ./gs_tensor.hweb:24,
                 from ./t_container.hweb:53,
                 from ./stack_container.hweb:87,
                 from ./faa_di_bruno.hweb:18,
                 from ./faa_di_bruno.cweb:10:
./twod_matrix.hweb:29:20: fatal error: matio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [libdynare___a-faa_di_bruno.o] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
dpkg: error processing package dynare-matlab (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=630160) that was fixed in version 4.2.1-2.

Comment: @Raphael Can't see why it would help. I did try, and also purged the package and reinstalled again. Nothing. Same error.

Comment: @Ron I'm installing 4.4.3. Maybe a new bug?

Comment: could be..try 4.2.1-2 if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution [here](http://www.dynare.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=5564). It seems to be a bug of the package for Ubuntu. Basically, the dependencies are not correct, as the library libmatio is missing. The problem is solved by first installing that library via `sudo apt-get install libmatio-dev`, and then installing `dynare-matlab`.

Then, dynare works.

PD: I am using package 4.4.1 instead of 4.4.3. Yet, according to [known bugs](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/KnownBugs), this error is not yet acknowledged. I submitted the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dynare/+bug/1537380).